# Can a Makefile take dependancies of a rule from a variable and insert into a recipe?

Tags: makefile

Specifically I'm thinking of a "clean" rule to remove leftover files.

```
files=file1 file2
clean:
    rm -f $(files)
file1: file1dependancy.o
```

How can I make clean automatically `rm -f` `file1dependancy.o` or is that even possible?

Comment: Your clean rules should not depend on anything; if they do, `make` has to try building those things before it can remove them, which is pointless and may cause the cleanup to fail (if the build is currently broken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the structure of the makefile would look something like:

```
RM_F  = rm -f
FILES = file1 file2

all:   ${FILES}

FILE1.o = file1dependency.o

file1: ${FILE1.o}
    ...build command mentioning ${FILE1.o}...

FILE2.o = file2.dependency.o

file2: ${FILE2.o}
    ...build command mentioning ${FILE2.o}...

clean:
    ${RM_F} ${FILE1.o} ${FILE2.o} ${FILES|
```

Depending on your version of `make`, there might be a macro for 'all the dependencies'; it isn't in [`POSIX make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html), though.

Comment: So I just use variables for the different dependancy lists?

Comment: That's the traditional way to do it when there are multiple files in the dependency list, or when the inference rules won't work (because you create an executable `javelin` from a source file `discus.c`, perhaps). I've always used `${...}` notation in `makefile`s; many people use `$(...)` instead, and `make` itself doesn't mind which you use. If I was doing the job really thoroughly, I'd have `FILE1 = file1; FILE2 = file2; FILES = ${FILE1} ${FILE2}` (on three lines) and then have targets `${FILE1}: ${FILE1.o}` etc. This avoids repeating a raw name. The `$@` macro can be used in the build rule.